# Wireguard-set DNS in resolv.conf removed after resuming from sleep

Tags: linux, networking, dns, wireguard

My Wireguard config sets a DNS server which is necessary to access my company's resources.

When activating the tunnel, everything works fine and `resolv.conf` contains the DNS specified in de wireguard config with `DNS = 10.1.1.1`.

However, after putting the laptop to sleep and resuming from sleep, `resolv.conf` again contains the standard network DNS even though the wireguard tunnel is still active.

Replacing systemd-resolved by openresolv did not help immediately.

How can I make (Ubuntu) Linux revert to the standard network DNS **only** after I deactivate the Wireguard tunnel?

Comment: What are you using to set up your wireguard tunnnel? wg-quick? What are you using to manage your other interfaces? If you are using network-manager, it is probably reactivating wifi when your laptop wakes up and reconfiguring the network through DHCP and thus resetting DNS. If that's the case, I recommend you manage wireguard using network-manager itself.

Comment: using `wg-quick` yes. The other interfaces I presume are managed by the `network-manager` service but I am not sure how to manage wireguard using network-manager?

Comment: Well, there is always the manual. The one for network-manager is a little bit daunting, however. There are also a couple of tutorials online. I recommend [this one](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2019/03/15/wireguard-in-networkmanager/). I don't know if nm does this automatically (I don't use it myself) but make sure that the wireguard interface is set up after the other ones to avoid the same problem happening again.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the guide and now it will automatically connect to wireguard every time it wakes up from sleep (or never, with autoconnect set to `no`) but neither behaviour is always desired. I want it to keep the tunnel and DNS settings in the same state as before the interruption, with the Wireguard DNS taking priority over the DHCP DNS if the tunnel is active.